# What is the better way to wrap a FFI struct that owns or borrows data?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have an Image struct that can be constructed from a `Vec<u8>` or a `&[u8]`.
It represents an image object in C library (ffi module).

```
struct Image { ptr: *mut c_void };

impl Image {
    fn from_vec(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Image {
        // transfer ownership to gobject system
        let ptr = unsafe {
            ffi::new(
                vec.as_ptr() as *const c_void,
                vec.len(),
                ..
            )
        };
        std::mem::forget(vec);
        Image { ptr }
    }
    fn from_ref(data: &[u8]) -> Image {
        // gobject doesn't free data on Drop
        let ptr = unsafe {
            ffi::new_ref(
                data.as_ptr() as *const c_void,
                data.len(),
                ..
            )
        };
        Image { ptr }
    }

    fn resize(&self, ..) -> Image {
        let new_ptr = unsafe { ffi::resize(self.ptr) };
        Image { new_ptr }
    }
}

impl Drop for Image {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            ffi::g_object_unref(self.ptr as *mut c_void);
        }
    }
}
```

The Image struct has only raw pointer and no borrow, so the compiler puts no lifetime constraint on the output of resize operation.

with a vector, this is ok:

```
let img1 = Image::from_vec(pixels); // consume pixels
let img2 = img1.resize(..);
return img2;
// when img2 is released, gobject system will release pixels as well
```

However, with a reference, this is a problem:

```
let pixels = Vec::new(..);
let img1 = Image::from_ref(&pixels);
let img2 = img1.resize(..)
return img2;
// danger: img2's gobject has a raw pointer to pixels
```

The compiler doesn't complain, but to prevent this case, I want the compiler to complain by adding a lifetime.

A working solution I know is to have two versions of Image, owned and borrowed. (like String/&str). However I don't want to repeat the same code which differs only in return type:

```
impl OwnedImage {
    fn resize(..) -> OwnedImage {
        let new_ptr = unsafe { ffi::resize(self.ptr) };
        OwnedImage{ptr:new_ptr}
    }
}

// ScopedImage needs a PhantomData.
struct ScopedImage<'a> { ptr: *mut c_void, marker: PhantomData<&'a ()> }
impl<'a> ScopedImage<'a> {
    fn resize(..) -> ScopedImage<'a> {
        let new_ptr = unsafe { ffi::resize(self.ptr) };
        ScopedImage{ptr:new_ptr, PhantomData}
    }
}

let pixels = Vec::new(..);
let img1 = ScopedImage::from_ref(&pixels);
let img2 = img1.resize(..);
return img2; // error, as I intended.
```

Unlike &str/String, two types differ only in whether the compiler complains or not for some cases.

My question is if it is possible to incorporate two types into one with lifetime parameter.

My first idea was having two lifetimes 'a and 'b, where 'a represents self's scope and 'b represents the scope of returned objects.
For reference image, I want to enforce 'a == 'b but I am not sure how to achieve that.

```
    // for vec, 'a!='b. for ref, 'a=='b

    struct Image<'a, 'b> { ptr, ?? }

    // this type parameter relationship is
    //    enforced at the construction

    from_vec(..) -> Image<'a,'a>
    from_ref<'b> (&'a data) -> Image<'a,'b>

    resize<'b>(&self, ..) -> Image<'b>
```

Or with one lifetime:

```
    type R = (Image:'a  or Image:'b);
    resize(&self, ..) -> R // R: return type, decided on construction
```

Or split into two structs, `OwnedImage` and `ScopedImage` and implement operations in a trait:

```
    trait ImageTrait<'a> {
        type OutputImage: 'a;

        fn resize(..) -> Self::OutputImage {
            ..
        }
    }

    impl<'a> ImageTrait<'a> for OwnedImage {
        type OutputImage = OwnedImage;
    }

    impl<'a, 'b> ImageTrait<'b> for ScopedImage {
        type OutputImage = ScopedImage;
    }
```

Or, searching 'rust lifetime as type association' gives me this RFC:
https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1598
(I am reading this. Is this applicable to my case?)

This is the first time I am writing a serious Rust code with complex generics and lifetimes.
I am not actually asking which is better (though I wonder their pros/cons and which is idiomatic), I just don't even know which of these options are possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm reading this correctly but you may want to look at [owning_ref](https://docs.rs/owning_ref/0.3.3/owning_ref/).

Comment: `from_vec` is definitely not safe. The `Vec` will be dropped when the function returns, invalidating the pointer. You need to at least `mem::forget(vec)` to make it work

Comment: I don't see how this question will not be opinion-based, which is explicitly offtopic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: However, it might be a duplicate of [How do I handle an FFI unsized type that could be owned or borrowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613798/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to better explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I don't think your `resize` function can exist, because you don't retain any information about the provenance of your pointer. You want the function to return an owned `Image` when `self` is owned, and a borrowed one when `self` is borrowed, but you aren't keeping track of any way to distinguish them. What does `ffi::resize` do?

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer. The question is not about how to manage FFI objects, but adding lifetime restriction on the purpose. My intention was to keep track of vec/ref distinction with lifetime specifier. (propagating lifetime from new_from_vec / new_from_ref).

Comment: ffi::resize performs an image resize and returns a new ffi image's pointer. ffi::resize doesn't care if the data is from vec/ref, however, the resized image may reference the input pixel data.

Comment: On the contrary, I think this is all about managing FFI objects. How can `fn resize(..) -> OwnedImage` be safe, if *the resized image may reference the input pixel data*?

Comment: Also, I think you don't realize that the `Vec` you called `mem::forget` on can never be freed. Rust's allocator has to free the data and, unless you save the vector's original capacity and call `Vec::from_raw_parts` to reconstitute it, that `Vec` is leaked forever. Passing it to C's `free` or to `g_object_unref` may do nothing, or may corrupt data, but it won't free the slice.

Comment: I say it is safe because rust code cannot do unsafe actions: rust code transferred the ownership to ffi and never accidently access to it again. if we trust ffi will reliably deallocate the object, the rust code can forget about it. (although we lost the control 'when' it is deallocated, this has nothing to do with data race)

Comment: Rust memory should be deallocated by Rust <- you are right, I missed that. Maybe I need to add another C layer to add callback to Rust deallocator. Also you are right that this is due to FFI. I want an explicit lifetime because the context is hidden behind a raw pointer and not exposed to the compiler. Assuming I solved the deallocation issue, do you think the question is valid? Or do you know any idiomatic pattern for this kind of case and I should not have used just a raw pointer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170173/discussion-between-trentcl-and-mq7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Struct**

```
pub struct Image<'a> {
    pub c: *mut ffi::Image,
    marker: PhantomData<&'a()>,
}
```

**Deallocation callback**

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn cleanup(ptr: *mut ffi::Image, user_data: *mut c_void) {
    let b: Box<Box<[u8]>> = Box::from_raw(user_data as *mut Box<[u8]>);
    println!(" >>>> releasing slice of len {}", b.len());
    drop(b);
}
```

**Reference constructor**

```
impl<'a> Image<'a> {
    pub fn from_memory_reference(buf: &'a [u8] /* ... */) -> Result<Image, Box<Error>> {
        let c = unsafe {
            ffi::image_new_from_memory(
                buf.as_ptr() as *const c_void,
                // ...
            )
        };

        Ok(Image {
            ptr: c,
            PhantomData,
        })
    }
}
```

**Owned constructor**

The solution is leaving the parameter `'a` as under-determined.

```
impl<'a> Image<'a> {
    pub fn from_memory(buf: Vec<u8> /* ... */) -> Result<Image<'a>, Box<Error>> {
        let b: Box<[_]> = buf.into_boxed_slice();
        let c = unsafe {
            ffi::image_new_from_memory(
                b.as_ptr() as *const c_void,
                // ...
            )
        };

        let bb: Box<Box<_>> = Box::new(b);
        let raw: *mut c_void = Box::into_raw(bb) as *mut c_void;

        unsafe {
            let callback: unsafe extern "C" fn() = ::std::mem::transmute(cleanup as *const ());

            ffi::g_signal_connect_data(
                c as *mut c_void,
                "close_signal\0".as_ptr() as *const c_char,
                Some(callback),
                raw,
                None,
                ffi::GConnectFlags::G_CONNECT_AFTER,
            );
        };

        Ok(Image {
            ptr: c,
            PhantomData,
        })
    }
}
```

**Operation**

```
fn resize(&self, scale: f64) -> Result<Image, Box<Error>> {
    // ...
}
```

**Reference test**

```
let _img: Image = {
    let pixels = vec![0; 256 * 256 * 3];
    Image::from_memory_reference(&pixels, /* ... */).unwrap()
    //~^ ERROR `pixels` does not live long enough
};
```

**Owned test**

```
let _img: Image = {
    let pixels = vec![0; 256 * 256 * 3];
    Image::from_memory(pixels, /* ... */).unwrap()
}; // Ok
```

A downside is that, when writing APIs, I need to be fully aware of lifetime elision rules, otherwise it might silently allow bad usages.

Comment: `drop(b);` is unneeded — values are dropped at the end of the block. `let _img: Image` doesn't need the type, it's inferred.