# How can one force Rust to take ownership of memory allocated other than by its safe methods?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, rust, heap-memory, ownership

In his February 2018 note titled "[Memory Safety in Rust: 
A Case Study with C](http://willcrichton.net/notes/rust-memory-safety/)", Will Crichton wrote:

> Rust provides the ability to take ownership of raw pointers, which we do using [`slice::from_raw_parts_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts_mut.html) and [`Box::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) which tells Rust to treat the memory pointer as a heap-allocated array. After transferring ownership, assuming the memory is valid and of the right size/type, Rust applies its usual memory safety and containment checks.

The relevant part of his code to which the above refers is:

```rust
let mut new_data = unsafe {
    let ptr = Heap::default()
        .alloc(Layout::array::<isize>(new_capacity).unwrap())
        .unwrap() as *mut isize;
    Box::from_raw(slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, new_capacity))
};
```

However, the documentation for [`Box::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) states (emphasis added):

> Since the way Box allocates and releases memory is unspecified, ***the only valid pointer to pass to this function*** is the one taken from another Box via the [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) function.

For the avoidance of doubt, the (experimental) [`Heap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/heap/struct.Heap.html) API used above to perform memory allocation (since removed in Rust 1.27.0) directly called `__rust_alloc` in its [`alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.2/src/alloc/heap.rs.html#82-92) method—and therefore `ptr` was *not* obtained from `Box::into_raw`.

Is it valid, albeit unsupported, to pass to `Box::from_raw` raw pointers to freshly allocated memory in order to have Rust take ownership of that memory and enforce its usual safety and containment checks?  In particular, will Rust deallocate that memory when the arising Box is destroyed?

If not, how *can* one force Rust to take such ownership of memory allocated other than by its safe methods?

Comment: [Related PR from 2019-02-05](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/58183)

Comment: "If not, how can one force Rust to take such ownership of memory allocated other than by its safe methods?" by definition this make no sense. Also, I will advice to not use `Box::from_raw` with pointer that doesn't come from `Box`, first even if it "could be correct in some case" this could go wrong fast, secondly, I doubt that a good API in C will give you the care to release a resource, except some case where you can just call `free` and I think it's better to call `free` that to guess if box would have too.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it valid, albeit unsupported, to pass to `Box::from_raw` raw pointers to freshly allocated memory

No, it is not valid.

> In particular, will Rust deallocate that memory when the arising `Box` is destroyed?

Yes, and this is the reason why it's invalid.

Memory allocators provide *paired* allocation and deallocation routines. When you allocate a piece of memory with one allocator, **you must free it with that allocator**.

If you don't, when the allocator doing the deallocation goes to perform whatever bookkeeping it needs to do, it won't know about that piece of memory. The allocator that actually did the allocation will never mark that memory as unavailable.

These concerns aren't made up, either. I've [submitted patches to GLib](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/commit/e1d80e9f7c4d2be53f286dd62349b49a06a8e636) to correct places where mismatched allocations / deallocations occurred and caused real problems in the wild.

> Rust to take such ownership of memory allocated

At the level of raw pointers, ownership is largely a state of mind, just like it is in C or C++. To *own* something here means that you are responsible for cleaning it up appropriately.

`malloc` and `free` are paired allocation/deallocation methods. You could create your own type and implement `Drop` for it:

```
use libc::{free, malloc};
use std::{ffi::c_void, mem};

struct MallocBox(*mut i32);

impl MallocBox {
    fn new(v: i32) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let p = malloc(mem::size_of::<i32>()) as *mut i32;
            *p = v;
            Self(p)
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for MallocBox {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { free(self.0 as *mut c_void) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    MallocBox::new(42);
}
```

A real implementation would also implement `Deref` and probably many other traits so that this type is ergonomic to use.

It would be annoying to have to create a `MallocBox` and `JeMallocBox` and a `MyCustomAllocBox`, which is why [RFC 1398](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1398-kinds-of-allocators.html) proposes a shared trait for allocators. Related [work is progressing](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/58457) to convert `Box<T>` into `Box<T, A: Alloc + Default = Global>`.

> how can one force Rust

There's no concept of "forcing" Rust to do anything, much less when it comes to low level details like this. For example, there's no guarantee that the C code that allocated the pointer doesn't try to free the pointer itself. In an FFI world, ownership is a cooperative agreement.

---

See also:

- [How do I handle an FFI unsized type that could be owned or borrowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613798/155423)
- [What is the better way to wrap a FFI struct that owns or borrows data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50107792/155423)

Comment: I’m actually looking to allocate memory from within Rust (in order to instantiate a custom DST).  My question is, if I use Rust’s allocator to allocate memory and then point at that memory with a (correctly-typed) fat raw pointer, can such pointer be passed to `Box::from_raw` in order for Rust to assume all further responsibility for that memory (ie ownership, borrowing, deallocation etc)?