# How to take ownership of a C pointer in Rust and drop it appropriately?

Tags: c, rust, ffi, ownership

I'm calling a C constructor function `keyNew` that allocates memory for a `Key` struct and returns a `*mut Key` to the Rust side. Is it appropriate to use `Box::from_raw` to wrap the pointer and take ownership of it?

I could also return the raw pointer directly, but this makes for a very ugly API and is not idiomatic to Rust.

I also want to implement the Drop Trait on the Key, such that the destructor function `keyDel` is automatically called, which would be an improvement over the manual calls in C. This is a much nicer API in my opinion. However implementing the Drop Trait requires that the Copy Trait is not implemented, so dereferencing the raw pointer is no longer possible due to "move out of dereferenced content".

They Key was generated by rust-bindgen

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Key {
    _unused: [u8; 0],
}
```

The constructor for `Key` is implemented like this

```rust
fn new() -> Box<Key> {
    unsafe { Box::from_raw(keyNew(0 as *const i8)) }
}
```

And the destructor

```rust
impl Drop for Key {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { keyDel(self) };
    }
}
```

It all works wonderfully, I can use a `Box<Key` like a `Key` due to Deref and `keyDel` is automatically called when the `Box<Key` goes out of scpe. However I am not sure if it's appropriate, since the Rust documentation has this to say about `Box::from_raw`

> After calling this function, the raw pointer is owned by the resulting Box. Specifically, the Box destructor will call the destructor of T and free the allocated memory. Since the way Box allocates and releases memory is unspecified, the only valid pointer to pass to this function is the one taken from another Box via the Box::into_raw function.

I am not calling `Box::into_raw` later, so is this all still valid memory-wise? And if not, what is an alternative way to take ownership of the returned `*mut Key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to use Box::from_raw to wrap the pointer and take ownership of it?

The [documentation for `from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) answers this for you:

> Since the way Box allocates and releases memory is unspecified, the only valid pointer to pass to this function is the one taken from another Box via the `Box::into_raw` function.

which means that your current usage is unspecified.

> I also want to implement the Drop Trait on the Key, such that the destructor function keyDel is automatically called

You should not implement `Drop` for `Key` because `Key` is not allocated by Rust. You would ideally make your own wrapper type that uses its *own* drop to call `keyDel` with the pointer. For instance:

```
struct KeyWrapper {
  ptr: NonNull<Key>
}
impl Drop for KeyWrapper {
  fn drop(&mut self) {
    keyDel(self.ptr.as_ptr())
  }
}
impl KeyWrapper {
  fn new() {
    KeyWrapper {
      ptr: NonNull::new(keyNew(0 as *const i8))
    }
  }

  fn someUtil(&self) {
    // As an example, you could call through to some C function.
    keySomeUtil(self.ptr.as_ptr())
  }
}
```

This way on the Rust side you are only interacting with the type that wraps the pointer, and it will call `keyDel` when it is dropped. It is your job to make sure this wrapper type only performs safe operations via the C API so as not to invalidate Rust's safety guarantees.

Related:

- [How can one force Rust to take ownership of memory allocated other than by its safe methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849928/how-can-one-force-rust-to-take-ownership-of-memory-allocated-other-than-by-its-s/54858033#54858033)