# How to wrap one C pointer? Use *mut T, Nonnull<T> or Unique<T>?

Tags: rust

I'm calling a C constructor function that allocates memory returns one pointer.

I found some similar questions.
they use [Nonnull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225328/how-to-take-ownership-of-a-c-pointer-in-rust-and-drop-it-appropriately) or [*mut T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849928/how-can-one-force-rust-to-take-ownership-of-memory-allocated-other-than-by-its-s/54858033#54858033) to wrap it.

And I also found another similar structure `Unique`, it will take the ownership of `T`.

This makes me wonder, what is the difference between them and how should I choose?

Comment: Is there anything not clarified by the documentation of [`NonNull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/ptr/struct.NonNull.html)? `Unique` is a private type in the standard library, not meant to be used directly.

Comment: @E_net4-MrDownvoter I'm too stupid to notice that `Unique` is an internally used struct. Thanks for your answer~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NonNull` if your pointer is never null. Use `*const T` or `*mut T` otherwise.

`Unique` is a private pointer for the standard library, you cannot use it (I think it was used to be exposed unstably, but not anymore). It represents an owned type: for example, [it is used for `Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#178) [and `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#53). It is basically `NonNull`, although it has some differences because it is considered owned: it impls `Send`/`Sync` (and other auto traits) if `T` does, and it is considered owned for the aliasing model and Miri (although [it is not obvious we want that](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/326)).